# Conditional method delegation using ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Is it possible to do a conditional call within bytebuddy's method delegation call? Suppose we have the following case:

```
Method serviceMethod = serviceHandler.getClass()
                .getDeclaredMethod(methodName, String.class, String.class, Object.class);
this.serviceHandler= byteBuddy.subclass(serviceHandler.getClass()).method(ElementMatchers.named("handleService"))
                .intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE.andThen(MethodCall.invoke(handleMethod).withArgument(0, 1, 2))).make().load(getClass().getClassLoader()).getLoaded().newInstance();
```

Can we do something like "only if super method call returns true then call subclasses method"? That would be a conditioned "andThen":

```
intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE.**andThenIfConditionFullfilled**(MethodCall.invoke(handleMethod)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible, unless if you implement your own `Implementation`. Conditional code quickly gets complicated. Byte Buddy is aiming for generating as little code as possible.

Possibly, use `Advice` for a byte code template if you wanted to avoid delegation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is it right, when the Method.invoke() should take place for a method within another class, we need a "delegate"-field to that method? In case of not doing so i get an illegalstateexception ("cannot invoke method....").